# ImportError: No module named UDPInterface

Tags: python

I am trying to build a Python app and ran into this import error:
`ImportError: No module named UDPInterface`

I am new to Python and hence I am unsure what dependency should I `pip` install. Tried searching on the internet but couldn't find anything useful. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
from Functions import *
from ScriptComms import *
from ScriptForms import *
from IPInterface import TCP_APIInterface
from multiprocessing.synchronize import Lock
import UDPInterface
```

Comment: Can you post your python code where the import happens? We don't need all of it just the line that imports `UDPInterface`

Comment: @Adam - Its actually a huge script, posting the affected lines below:
'from Functions import *
from ScriptComms import *
from ScriptForms import *
from IPInterface import TCP_APIInterface
from multiprocessing.synchronize import Lock
import UDPInterface'

Error which points to the last import line:
import UDPInterface
ImportError: No module named UDPInterface

Comment: Yeah we only need the line where the import actually happens. Also edit your post and put it there. Not in comments.

Comment: What makes you believe that `UDPInterface` is something that you should be importing?  Are you following a tutorial or reading some instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your imports it looks like it can't find the local python file `UDPInterface.py`. I believe it to be local given I cannot find any python module with that [name](https://pypi.org/search/?q=udpinterface). In the same directory level of your script there should be a file named `UDPInterface.py`. Could also be a simple typo in the filename or import. That or `UDPInterface` is in a sub/another directory and the import should be adjusted as so.

PS. You should avoid using `*` imports in Python (generally other languages also) as it can create namespace collisions (two modules with functions/classes/variables of the same name). Try `from my_module import func1, func2` as it is more explicit and makes it easier to track down the source of the function/class/variable

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I could resolve the issue. Was thinking as this has to do something with a missing package but turned out to be an issue with not properly importing the project directory. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. You should read [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).